# How to view Dependencies Diagram in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Using the [Jetbrains guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/working-with-maven-dependencies.html), I'm unable to get the UML dependency diagram loaded.  There doesn't appear to be any requirements to utilize this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I didn't have the UML plugin enabled.